# Nginx can not proxy pass to Django docker container

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I'm running my Django app in docker-compose and I'm exposing port 8000.
I have Nginx installed in the VM without docker and I want it to forward requets to my Django app, I tried to use host network in my docker-compose and create an external network but nothing worked and I'm always getting 502 Bad gateway

this my nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}
http{
     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; #includes all files of file type.conf


server {
    listen   80;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /var/lib/docker/volumes/app1_django-static;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /var/lib/docker/volumes/app1_django-media;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }
    #For favicon
    location  /favicon.ico {
        alias /code/assets/favicon.ico;
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /code/templates/;
    }
}

}
```

and this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  web:
    network_mode: host
    image: nggyapp/newsapp:1.0.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: django-static
        target: /code/static
      - type: volume
        source: django-media
        target: /code/media
    environment:
      - "DEBUG_MODE=False"
      - "DB_HOST=.."
      - "DB_PORT=5432"
      - "DB_NAME=db"
      - "DB_USERNAME=.."
      - "DB_PASSWORD=.."
volumes:
  django-static:
  django-media:
```

Comment: Can you `curl http://localhost:8000/` from your VM ?

Comment: yes, when I do curl http://localhost:8000; i get the HTML template